# angular 8 firefox 50 and IE 11 not working

Tags: angular, firefox

new app with angular 8 is not working on firefox 50 and IE11, it only works on chrome.
When we changed target from es2015 to es5 then it works.

I served app with --verbose and on both firefox and IE I can see header app is ready.
and rest is blank screen. No errors in console.

This is my package.json

```
    "name": "angular-navigation-poc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:webcomponent": "ng build -c webcomponent --output-hashing=none && node build-angular-element.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/elements": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.11",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.4",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.3.1",
    "@webcomponents/shadydom": "^1.7.0",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "core-js-bundle": "^3.4.2",
    "document-register-element": "1.8.1",
    "elements-zone-strategy": "^8.0.0",
    "material-icons": "^0.3.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^8.0.3",
    "ngx-unused-css": "^1.2.1",
    "promise-polyfill": "8.1.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "rxjs-observable-store": "^2.0.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.12",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.11",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
```

Is there anything else I can check , try ?

Comment: Can you check in both console. JS and angular-cli that you have no error ? Maybe do you load async data, maybe it has something to do with that.

Comment: I've had something similar, i was fetching data in the constructor and not in the `ngOnInit` function. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: for it to work in IE11 you need to change the target to ES5 as you mentioned. So unsure on what you want to achieve

Comment: @Nicolas checked that , no errors, there should be some ui without asking for data so for sure not releated with fetching data in constructor, and it works in chrome